# Run a job on hadoop cluster

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to submit a job on a hadoop cluster and got this error. Do you have any idea how can I fix it? or at least generally what are the possibilities?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from a null string
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:99)
Can not create a Path from a null string
null
```

and this is the bash script to submit my job.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 SUBMIT_SCRIPT=/usr/local/job_submit.sh
 JAR_LOC="$PWD/Models.jar"
 ORG_ID="2"
 INPUT_LOC=/starting/part*
 OUTPUT_LOC=/user/v/output

 hadoop fs -rm -r ${OUTPUT_LOC}
 LIB="$JAR_LOC" \
         $SUBMIT_SCRIPT \
         -j DataJob \
         -m PassThrough -r PassThrough \
         -DinputPath=${INPUT_LOC}\
         -DoutputPath=${OUTPUT_LOC}

 #hadoop fs -cat ${OUTPUT_LOC}/part* > out.txt
```

Comment: What is the command which you are using?

Comment: We'll need to see the contents of job_submit.sh too.

Comment: I'm going to speculate that if you move the `-Dk=v` arguments to after $SUBMIT_SCRIPT it will probably work - the generic arguments must be placed before non-generic arguments.